# Reading action params in ACF's matchCallback

Tags: php, yii, callback, yii2, access-control

I have a typical / classical ACF declaration, in my *app-basic* application, that uses `matchCallback`:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                    'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                        echo 'Yii::$app->controller->actionParams = '.print_r(Yii::$app->controller->actionParams, TRUE);
                        echo '$action->controller->actionParams = '.print_r($action->controller->actionParams, TRUE);
                        echo '$action = '.print_r($action, TRUE);
                        die();
                    }
                ],
            ],
        ]
    ];
}
```

To my surprise, I found this:

[image]

How can this be true? Why action parameters are not available when evaluating `matchCallback`?

And -- of course -- how to read them, if my access rule requires to check one of action parameters to judge, whether user can access particular action or not?

**EDIT**: You can, of course, read action parameters using the *brutal* way of:

```
echo '$_GET = '.print_r($_GET, TRUE);
```

But, I don't like brutal solutions and it really bothers me, why `actionParams` are empty at this stage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Controller class has method `bindActionParams()` which is invoked by *\yii\base\Action* when it begins to run with the given parameters. So at first controller invoke an action method and run it with params and then action bind its params to controller. But *AccessControl* check is executing much earlier before action is running, that's why `actionParams` are empty. Here is an [request lifecycle](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-workflow.html#request-lifecycle). As you can see before action gets executed controller performs filters, one of which is *AccessControl*.

If you dont like "brutal" way, consider use of `Yii::$app->request->get()` which also will test parameter for *isset*.

Comment: Sounds logical and I expected, that this happens due to ACF being run much earlier than params biding. Care to copy this answer to [Yii forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/64662-reading-action-params-in-acfs-matchcallback) as well, so readers of that source will also get an answer. Thank you.